# Removal from tree with parent pointer and left subtree and right subtree height

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I have a problem with removal from binary tree with nodes that each node keeps height of left and right subtree and pointer to parent. 
Adding is ok i suppose?
I am getting wrong heights and wrong parent pointers as well as I am missing some part of tree while removal.
How should i change my removal and linking functions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Node 
{
    int data;
    Node* parent;
    Node* leftChild;
    Node* rightChild;
    int leftHeight;
    int rightHeight;
};

void DisplayTreeInOrder(struct Node* root)
{
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        DisplayTreeInOrder(root->leftChild);
        printf("Node : %d, ", root->data);
        printf(" Height left : %d, ", root->leftHeight);
        printf(" Height right : %d, ", root->rightHeight);
        if (root->parent == NULL)
        {
            printf("Parent : NULL \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Parent : %d \n", root->parent->data);
        }
        DisplayTreeInOrder(root->rightChild);
    }
}

Node* CreateNode(int data, Node* parent = nullptr)
{
        struct Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->parent = parent;
        newNode->leftChild = nullptr;
        newNode->rightChild = nullptr;
        newNode->leftHeight = 0;
        newNode->rightHeight = 0;
        return newNode;
}

void AddHeights(Node* newNode) 
{
    Node* parent = newNode->parent;

    while (parent != nullptr)
    {
        if (parent->leftChild == newNode)
        {
            parent->leftHeight++;
            if (parent->leftHeight <= parent->rightHeight)
            {
                break;
            }
            newNode = parent;
            parent = parent->parent;
        }
        else
        {
            parent->rightHeight++;
            if (parent->rightHeight <= parent->leftHeight)
            {
                break;
            }
            newNode = parent;
            parent = parent->parent;
        }
    }
}

Node* AddToTree(Node* root, int data)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        return CreateNode(data, nullptr);
    }

    Node* temp = root;

    while (true)
    {
        if (data < temp->data)
        {
            if (temp->leftChild == nullptr)
            {
                Node* newNode = CreateNode(data, temp);
                temp->leftChild = newNode;
                AddHeights(newNode);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = temp->leftChild;
            }
        }

        else if (data > temp->data)
        {
            if (temp->rightChild == nullptr)
            {
                Node* newNode = CreateNode(data, temp);
                temp->rightChild = newNode;
                AddHeights(newNode);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = temp->rightChild;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return root;
}

Node* FindNode(struct Node* root, int dataToFind)
{
    while (root != nullptr)
    {
        if (dataToFind > root->data)
        {
            root = root->rightChild;
        }

        else if (dataToFind < root->data)
        {
            root = root->leftChild;
        }
        else
        {
            return root;
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}

Node* minValueNode(struct Node* node)
{
    Node* current = node;

    while (current && current->leftChild != nullptr)
    {
        current = current->leftChild;
    }

    return current;
}

void SubtractHeights(Node* newNode)
{
    Node* parent = newNode->parent;

    int max = std::max(parent->leftHeight, parent->rightHeight);

    while (parent != nullptr)
    {
        if (parent->leftChild == newNode)
        {
            parent->leftHeight--;
            if (parent->leftHeight <= max)
            {
                break;
            }
            newNode = parent;
            parent = parent->parent;
        }
        else
        {
            parent->rightHeight--;
            if (parent->rightHeight <= max)
            {
                break;
            }
            newNode = parent;
            parent = parent->parent;
        }
    }
}

void UnlinkChildFromParent(Node* node) 
{
    Node* parent = node->parent;
    if (parent == nullptr) 
    {
        return;
    }
    if (node == parent->leftChild)
    {
        parent->leftChild = nullptr;
    }
    else 
    {
        parent->rightChild = nullptr;
    }
}

Node* RemoveFromTree(Node *root, int value)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        return root;
    }

    Node* nodeToRemove = FindNode(root, value);
    if (nodeToRemove == nullptr)
    {
        return root;
    }

    else
    {
        if ((nodeToRemove->leftChild == nullptr) || (nodeToRemove->rightChild == nullptr))
        {
            Node* temp = nodeToRemove->leftChild ? nodeToRemove->leftChild : nodeToRemove->rightChild;

            if (temp == nullptr)
            {
                temp = nodeToRemove;
                SubtractHeights(nodeToRemove);
                UnlinkChildFromParent(nodeToRemove);
                nodeToRemove = nullptr;
            }
            else
            {
                Node* parentOfNodeToRemove = nodeToRemove->parent;
                *nodeToRemove = *temp;
                SubtractHeights(nodeToRemove);
                UnlinkChildFromParent(nodeToRemove);
            }

            delete temp;
        }

        else
        {
            Node* temp = minValueNode(nodeToRemove->rightChild);

            nodeToRemove->data = temp->data;

            nodeToRemove->rightChild = RemoveFromTree(nodeToRemove->rightChild, temp->data);
        }
    }

    return root;
}

int main()
{
    Node *ptrToTree = nullptr;
    ptrToTree = AddToTree(ptrToTree, 45);
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 46);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 47);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 44);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 10);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 11);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 12);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 13);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 14);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 19);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 66);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 100);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 9);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 48);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 8);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    AddToTree(ptrToTree, 8);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    RemoveFromTree(ptrToTree, 8);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    RemoveFromTree(ptrToTree, 10);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    RemoveFromTree(ptrToTree, 11);
    DisplayTreeInOrder(ptrToTree);
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

[How tree looks like and operations to perform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkjRa.png)

Comment: It's nice that the code can be compiled as it is. It's less nice that the main() is so long and there is no indication of what is the first wrong result you get. Do you think the first 2 removals (8, 10) are ok? The third one is clearly wrong...

Comment: No they are not okay. You can see in console while printing DisplayTreeInOrder that pointers to parents and heights are messed up. Main function is long just to print state of tree after each insertion/removal. First 2 removals should be ok since those nodes were added in tree, but they are not, since heights are wrong.

Comment: Yeah I can see the console output, but there are quite many lines in it once all the elements have been added, so it takes some time to get the idea of what the tree actually looks like. Stay tuned, I'll find out what's going on in several hours...

Comment: What is the motivation behind the ```max``` variable in the ```SubtractHeights()```? Why does the ```while``` break upon ```parent->XXheight <= max```?

Comment: Well, we should update heights only if new height is lower than it was. E.g left subtree was 3, right was 2. We have eliminated one node from left subtree so it should be 2. But it also should cause to update parent since overall height is no longer 3, but 2 and propagate change up to root of whole tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the node-removing code, so far I only figured out what's wrong with the first removal (8). I don't see why the variable `max` has been introduced into `SubtractHeights()`, what works is analogy to code in `AddHeights()`. If the condition
`parent->leftHeight <= max` on line 55 is changed to `parent->leftHeight < parent->rightHeight` and `parent->rightHeight <= max` on line 65 changed to `parent->rightHeight < parent->leftHeight`, the first removal seems to work all right. The behavior of the other 2 cases seems not to be changed by this.

I'll try to figure out the rest when/if you respond...

Comment: Well so what I should do now? In case of removal of node with right node having two nodes?

Comment: Haven't figured that out yet. Does what I wrote make sense to you?